# Is there a difference in my code and output?

Tags: stack

Just a quick question regarding stack.
I hope there wouldn't be any down vote.

```
S1 = stack()
s2 = stack()
```

does `S2.push(s1.pop())` is the same as S1.pop`(S2.push())`

I'm trying to invert the stack of S1 with the help of S2
Eg. if the number 3 is at the top of the stack S1, after calling s1.invert(), 3 will be at the bottom of s1